# Problemas com CDI + Weld no Wildfly

Tags: java, jpa, cdi

Estou tentado criar um `EntityManagerProducer` e ao que parece nos exemplos encontrados na internet algo bem simples, mas não está sendo.

Então conclui que estou fazendo algo de errado segue minha codificação e configuração. Ah meu `web.xml` não tem nenhuma configuração por se tratar apenas de uma API.

**BEAN.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">

</beans>
```

**EntityManagerProducer**

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerProducer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "ProjetoFinalPU")
    private EntityManagerFactory appFactory;

    @Produces
    @BancoPadrao
    public EntityManager createAppEntityManager() {
        return appFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void closeEntityManager(@Disposes EntityManager manager) {
        if (manager.isOpen()) {
            manager.close();
        }
    }    
}
```

**RamoDal**

```
public class RamoDal implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    @BancoPadrao
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public Ramo salvar(Ramo entidade) {
        entityManager.persist(entidade);
        return entidade;
    }

    public Ramo atualizar(Ramo entidade) {
        entityManager.merge(entidade);
        return entidade;
    }

    public List<Ramo> listar() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("select e from Ramo e").getResultList();
    }

    public void remover(Ramo entidade) {
        entityManager.remove(entidade);
    }

}
```

**BancoPadrao**

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface BancoPadrao {

}
```

**Erro:**

```
13:58:57,527 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"proptotipobackend-1.0.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"proptotipobackend-1.0.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type EntityManager with qualifiers @BancoPadrao
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @BancoPadrao private com.mycompany.proptotipobackend.dal.RamoDal.entityManager
  at com.mycompany.proptotipobackend.dal.RamoDal.entityManager(RamoDal.java:0)
"},
```

Já tenti alterar os escopos substituir o `@PersistenceUnit` e o erro persiste.

Answer (score 0):

Remova essas linhas do seu arquivo de configuração (standalone.xml):

```
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
```

E

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>
```

Comment: Fiz o que você falou e o erro persistiu.